# Запуск анимации при наведении курсора

Tags: javascript, css

На некоторых сайтах присутствует эффект, который запускает анимацию при наведении курсора.
То есть вначале картинка неподвижна, но при наведении начинает вращаться.
Это реализуется только с помощью *JS*, или можно с *CSS* сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно же можно сделать на `css`. Это давно не секрет. Уже не один год.
Главное при этом хорошо изучить.
Вот простой пример:

```css
    #test {
      background-color: #f00;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    #test:hover {
      background-color: #fc3;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
      -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
      transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
    }
    .grow {
      background-color: green;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    .grow:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<br />
<br />

<div class='grow'></div>
```

При должном навыке можно дела удивительные вещи:

```css
div {
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:75%;
}
div:nth-of-type(odd) { background:black; }
div:nth-of-type(even) { background:white; border:2px solid black; }
div:nth-of-type(11) {
  height:10px; width:10px;
  margin-top:-5px; margin-left:-5px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(10) {
  height:20px; width:20px;
  margin-top:-12px; margin-left:-12px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -2.7s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -2.7s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(9) {
  height:40px; width:40px;
  margin-top:-20px; margin-left:-20px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -2.4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -2.4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(8) {
  height:60px; width:60px;
  margin-top:-32px; margin-left:-32px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -2.1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -2.1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(7) {
  height:80px; width:80px;
  margin-top:-40px; margin-left:-40px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -1.8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -1.8s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(6) {
  height:100px; width:100px;
  margin-top:-52px; margin-left:-52px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(5) {
  height:120px; width:120px;
  margin-top:-60px; margin-left:-60px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  height:140px; width:140px;
  margin-top:-72px; margin-left:-72px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -0.9s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -0.9s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  height:160px; width:160px;
  margin-top:-80px; margin-left:-80px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -0.6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -0.6s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  height:180px; width:180px;
  margin-top:-92px; margin-left:-92px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s -0.3s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s -0.3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  height:200px; width:200px;
  margin-top:-100px; margin-left:-100px;
  -webkit-animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% { left:75% }
  50% { left:25%; }
  100% { left:75%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% { left:75% }
  50% { left:25%; }
  100% { left:75%; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
  border-radius:50%;
  height:2px; width:2px; /* To allow border-radius to work */
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  margin-top:-1px; margin-left:-1px;
  box-shadow:
    -75px -125px 0 40px #6cce74,
     75px -125px 0 40px #c18d46,
    150px    0px 0 40px #c14745,
     75px  125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
    -75px  125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
   -150px    0px 0 40px #76bdd1;
  -webkit-animation:rotate 12s infinite linear;
  animation:rotate 12s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  16.67% {
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
       75px -125px 0 40px #6cce74,
      150px    0px 0 40px #c18d46,
       75px  125px 0 40px #c14745,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #9c37a6;
  }
  33.33%   { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
       75px -125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
      150px    0px 0 40px #6cce74,
       75px  125px 0 40px #c18d46,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #c14745,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #2e1e5b;
  }
  50%      { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
       75px -125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
      150px    0px 0 40px #76bdd1,
       75px  125px 0 40px #6cce74,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #c18d46,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #c14745;
  }
  66.67%   { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #c14745,
       75px -125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
      150px    0px 0 40px #9c37a6,
       75px  125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #6cce74,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #c18d46;
  }
  88.88%   { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #c18d46,
       75px -125px 0 40px #c14745,
      150px    0px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
       75px  125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #6cce74;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #6cce74,
       75px -125px 0 40px #c18d46,
      150px    0px 0 40px #c14745,
       75px  125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #76bdd1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  16.67% {
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
       75px -125px 0 40px #6cce74,
      150px    0px 0 40px #c18d46,
       75px  125px 0 40px #c14745,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #9c37a6;
  }
  33.33%   { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
       75px -125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
      150px    0px 0 40px #6cce74,
       75px  125px 0 40px #c18d46,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #c14745,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #2e1e5b;
  }
  50%      { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
       75px -125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
      150px    0px 0 40px #76bdd1,
       75px  125px 0 40px #6cce74,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #c18d46,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #c14745;
  }
  66.67%   { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #c14745,
       75px -125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
      150px    0px 0 40px #9c37a6,
       75px  125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #6cce74,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #c18d46;
  }
  88.88%   { 
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #c18d46,
       75px -125px 0 40px #c14745,
      150px    0px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
       75px  125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #76bdd1,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #6cce74;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    box-shadow:
      -75px -125px 0 40px #6cce74,
       75px -125px 0 40px #c18d46,
      150px    0px 0 40px #c14745,
       75px  125px 0 40px #2e1e5b,
      -75px  125px 0 40px #9c37a6,
     -150px    0px 0 40px #76bdd1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Главное не забывать делать эту анимацию при наведении (**hover**) или при другом любом удобном и нужном вам моменте. При фокусе, к примеру.

О `css`  анимации множество ресурсов писано. В поисковике очень много ссылок на эту тему